# Add multiple HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `has_and_belong_to_many` relation between `Talk` and `RatingQuestion`. I want to add (or remove) the relation on hundreds of records at once.

I'm using a `for` loop, but it takes some time since there could be possibly thousands of talks. Any idea how I could improve the code below?

```
rq = RatingQuestion.find(rating_question_id)
talks.each do |talk|
  talk.rating_questions << rq unless talk.rating_questions.include?(rq)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move long-running tasks into a background job queue. Database writes are generally very expensive, so as you get into the mentioned thousands of associations, your request very well may time out.

You could probably improve the performance of this through bulk inserting, which bunches all your inserts into larger `INSERT` calls to the database.

**However**, this is a big indicator that you're going about the structure of your app poorly. Do *all* these records have to exist in the database? Could they be created as they're answered or manipulated instead of all up-front?

Comment: Usually these records are created when the parent object is created but sometimes the client wants to add more later. I inherited the code not long ago, we are going to make a major overhaul of the app in the upcoming months and this is on my radar as one of the things to fix structurally. Thanks for the help!